# Object References - Why Is It Referring to the Wrong Object?

Tags: java, oop, io

I am attempting to read a file where each line is to be used to created an object I've called `Food`. Each line is also comma-delimited, so I am using an instance of the `StringTokenizer` class to parse through the data. Here's a peak at the contents of the file I am using:

```
Aldi's Distribution Center,Gertrude ,Hagge,90411,3158,fruit & grapefruit,decay,15,cases,8422,40914

Campbell Soup Company,Roch,Carter,90410,8583,soup & tomato,short-dated,2,pallets,,

Kikkoman Foods,Arnold,Brown,90328,5045,marinade - herb  garlic,damaged,4,cases,,
```

The `Food` class has several instance variables, one of them being another class that I've defined called `Name`. `Name` has only two instance variables, one string for a first name and another for a last name. For some reason, I originally thought it'd be useful to create a function in my `Name` class that performed the following:

```
    public Name copy(){ 
        Name nameCopy = new Name(this.first, this.last); 
        return nameCopy; 
    }
```

Then, as I was creating the `Food` class, I created the following `get` method for `Name`:

```
    public Name getContact(){
        return contact.copy();
    }
```

My default and overloaded constructors for `Food` are the following:

```
public Food(){
    this("Google", new Name(), "091024", "8502", "Jiffy peanut butter", "other", 4399, "cases"); 
}

public Food(String corpName, Name contact, String date, String productCode, String description, String reason, int number, String cop){
    this.corpName = corpName;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.date = date;
    this.productCode = productCode;
    this.description = description;
    this.reason = reason;
    this.number = number;
    this.cop = cop;
}
```

So, I have my default constructor of `Name` part of the default constructor of `Food`.

**Here's the real meat and potatoes of what I'm getting at.** The code I use to parse through the data is the following:

```
    try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("foodBankInput.txt"));
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String stringRead = scan.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(stringRead,",");
            Food temp = new Food();
            temp.setCorpName(tokens.nextToken());
            temp.getContact().setLast(tokens.nextToken());
            temp.getContact().setFirst(tokens.nextToken());
            temp.setDate(tokens.nextToken());
            temp.setProductCode(tokens.nextToken());
            temp.setDescription(tokens.nextToken());
            temp.setReason(tokens.nextToken());
            String numberString = tokens.nextToken();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
            temp.setNumber(number);
            temp.setCoP(tokens.nextToken());
            list.insert((Food)temp);
            System.out.println(temp.toString() + "\n");
        }
        scan.close(); 
    }
```

`list` is an instance of a class that I've created called `FoodArrayList` which pretty much performs the same operations as the `ArrayList` class. My problem now is that if I keep `getContact()` as it is, each instance of `Food` in my array uses the default constructor of `Name`. Why does it do this? I understand that it will create multiple copies/instances of a `Name` object each time `copy()` is used. However, shouldn't each copy of the `Name` object have the same contents (first and last name) as the previous one, based on the way that I've defined `copy()`?

I understand that if I adjust my `getContact()` method to the following, my code will work as I want it to:

```
    public Name getContact(){ 
       return contact; 
    }
```

However, I still don't totally understand why this is the solution. Any input on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you create *temp* with the default constructor Food() which also assigns a contact to an object created from the default constructor Name().

Next you try to overwrite the values with setters, but when you call getContact() it returns a **copy**.  You are not changing the object that's associated with *temp*!

After you modified getContact(), you started returning the instance associated with the *temp* instance.